# Uncomment several lines in crontab using shell script

Tags: shell, cron

I would like to create shell script which will gonna uncomment several lines from crontab. So i would like to uncomment everything from 3rd to 6th line. My shell scripting experience is very low, so i would like to have some suggestions from you guys.

Thank you

Comment: Using the line number would be pretty poor practice, IMHO, and fraught with problems if anyone else ever adds even a comment near the start of the file. Please consider checking instead for some recognisable and unique aspect of the lines you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

This sed expression will replace lines 3 to 5...

`sed -i '3,5s/^#//g' yourcrontabFileLocation`

**Explain**

`sed -i`--> stream editor that uses regular expressions, `-i` edit the files in place

`'3,5s/^#//g'` --> Regular expression to replace from lines 3 to 5 the ones starting with "#".